# How to list the unique categorical values of a data frame column?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, unique

How to list (a list of distinct elements) the unique categorical values of a data frame column?

Comment: Depends on the class.

Answer (score 1):

```
ResultingList <- as.list(unique(df$ColumnName))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or with `purrr`:

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  select_if(is.factor) %>% 
  purrr::map(unique)
```